# Raised "processing.app.debug.RunnerException" Exception while uploading the sketch

Tags: arduino

I am unable to upload the **empty sketch** to **Arduino Leonardo pro micro**

I am facing this problem after I have been uploaded the last sketch

[image: ![](https://scontent.fdel24-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/81898870_2803648016410057_4303317360963485696_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_eui2=AeEsO6p6MfNWw9q-yjG8cQihKcD07Orre6sFnLfH3-upR7h2c8ami1JukJiWX2hxT2fDQ1qUhLg5J3MIhuQRJeYgzAZr7zOViS38rX_DvWdgIQ&_nc_ohc=-pgx3nE7tSQAQn63mQDzuDqZq7eVNMi6SRtGbQBrHGk_4nk1A89y0f-Sw&_nc_ht=scontent.fdel24-1.fna&oh=62c05a98ebe67986b113887df27c5fdf&oe=5E949761)]

Now when I am trying to upload the sketch I am getting the following error.

[image]

I have followed all the instructions to setup for Arduino development listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/arduino#Configuration). And as I said earlier, I was able to upload the sketches, and no `/dev/ttyACM0` is listed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons but in this case, its **the USB stack crashes**.

Press reset (short `RST` and `GND`), click upload, wait for the code to compile and for the status bar to say '**Uploading...**' and then release the button (RST and GND) on the board.